# force_ssl even behind nginx and generate https url

Tags: ssl, https, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to get force_ssl working. I mean I want to redirect someone trying to connect via http to https with the app itself.

The app is a dockerized released version behind Nginx. Actually Nginx is serving the SSL and I know that I can totally rely on Nginx to terminate the ssl connection and even taking care of the redirection of non https requests. But I want to understand how to make it work so if someday I skip the proxy I'll know how to do it.

My prod/config looks like that:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: "${PORT}"],
  url: [host: "${APP_URL}", port: "${APP_PORT}"],
  force_ssl: [hsts: true], #I tried different options without success
  server: true,
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  root: ".",
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version]
```

Actually when accessing the server via https everything runs as expected. But when using http address, the redirect url looks like: `https://%24%7Bapp_url%7D/` and it didn't work.

Maybe this happens because I didn't give a cert file and the whole process cannot be done without it? I was thinking that `force_ssl` is just a basic redirection if the request isn't https.

Finally I'm also trying to generate https url for instance in a mailer I've got something like this:

```
<%= password_url(MyApp.Endpoint, :reset_password_from_email, token: @token, email: @email) %>
```

But since my configuration seems not good it only generate http links not https.

Maybe should I separate this completely, making this 100% on Nginx side or 100% on the app side but not trying to mix them both?

Any help/idea/comment is welcome!

**EDIT**:

Last test with this:

```
force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto], subdomains: true, hsts: true, host: "${APP_URL}"]
```

result with the bad url: `https://%24%7Bapp_url%7D/`. So I think this is working but the var: `"${APP_URL}"`isn't converted to the real value. I'm digging on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hardcoding the `host: "${APP_URL}"` value resolves the problem as suspected in my last edit.

There's something wrong here because all other ENV_VAR are replaced by their values but not this one.